# Confusion Matrix for Text Sentiment Analysis in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to predict if a review sentiment is good or bad using RandomForestClassifier in python. My label is split into good or bad based on the reviewer rating from 1 to 5. Prediction is done using text in review text column. Before vectorizing, my data looks like this...
[image]

```html
#Apply TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=clean_text)
X_tfidf = tfidf_vect.fit_transform(df['Review_Text'])
print(X_tfidf.shape)
print(tfidf_vect.get_feature_names())

#Model Construction: RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix as cm

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tts(X_tfidf, df['Label'], test_size=0.3)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, max_depth=20, n_jobs=-1)
rf_model = rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = rf_model.predict(X_test)

precision, recall, fscore, support = score(y_test, y_pred, pos_label='Good',average='binary')

print('For sentiment = Good...\nPrecision: {} / Recall: {} / Accuracy: {}'.format(round(precision, 3),
                                                        round(recall, 3),
                                                        round((y_pred==y_test).sum() / len(y_pred),3)))

print(cm(y_test, y_pred))
```

---

My result is coming up as...

For sentiment = Good...
Precision: 0.795 / Recall: 1.0 / Accuracy: 0.795
[[   13  2618]
[    0 10166]]

Why does my confusion matrix look like that? What am I doing wrong?

I also tried to apply Naive Bayes as below:

```html
#vectorizing using cv

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer=clean_text)
X_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(df['Review_Text'])
print(X_counts.shape)
print(count_vect.get_feature_names())

#Model Construction: Multinomial Naive Bayes

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn import metrics

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tts(X_counts, df['Label'], test_size=0.3, random_state=1)

# Model Generation Using Multinomial Naive Bayes
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train, y_train)
predicted= clf.predict(X_test)

print("MultinomialNB Accuracy:", round(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, predicted),3))
print("Confusion Matrix:\n",metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, predicted))
```

My output was:
MultinomialNB Accuracy: 0.878
Confusion Matrix:
[[1420 1130]
[ 431 9816]]

This matrix is correct. i don't understand why the same doesn't with for RF. Is it something with my TFIDF?

Comment: what is your desired output

Comment: I want my model to be able to predict sentiment(good/badbased on rating) from the review text.

Comment: yes but in what format would you be so kind as to include an example output

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the input. I want a new column called predicted_label predicting Good/Bad based on reading the data from column review_text_clean using RF classifier. I have done the same with Naive Bayes and it seems to work just fine. I will include that in the summary.

Comment: I've added everything

Comment: let me do some research and I'll see if I can figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: In RF, I think that according to the precision and recall, if are correct then the confusion matrix should be like  row1: `[ 10166  2618]` and row2: `[ 0  13 ]` . Can you please double check.

Comment: @AKA I agree with you. What i don't understand is where I went wrong.